# How to sort the datetime value after converting it into a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In this query i am unable to order by right

> select CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(StartDate as date),101) +' - '
>               + CONVERT(varchar(10), cast(EndDate as date),101) Duration
>           from dbo.Calendar
>           order by CONVERT(DATE, StartDate, 101) desc;

It gives me the following result which is not ordered right
    mm/dd/yyyy

```
05/06/2013 - 06/29/2013
01/14/2013 - 04/26/2013
08/27/2012 - 12/15/2012
06/25/2012 - 08/18/2012
04/30/2012 - 06/23/2012
01/09/2012 - 04/23/2012
05/02/2011 - 08/22/2011
```

Comment: Are `StartDate` and `EndDate` date fields or varchar fields?

Comment: how do you _want_ it sorted?  Your results looks like it's sorted by start date descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting your order by to a varchar, leave it as a datetime.

```
select 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), 
    cast(StartDate as date),101) +' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), 
    cast(EndDate as date),101) Duration 
from 
    dbo.Calendar 
order by StartDate desc, EndDate;
```

Edit:

Added `EndDate` in your orderby as well, in case there are start dates that are the same

I misread your query initially.  You cast `StartDate` to a DateTime already, so the order is correct.

Adding `DESC` to your datetime means that the newest or most recent value is first, oldest is last.

Comment: I tried that, but the result is still the same as the above. Its order is still not right.

Comment: @user3324467 you ask for your results to be sorted by start date DESCENDING.  They are.

Comment: @user3324467, yes.  `ASC` (or no parameter) will reverse the order.

Comment: @user3324467 descending means newest or most recent to oldest.  So `05/06/2013` is the newest record and `05/02/2011` is the oldest

Comment: Thanks i was confused.

Comment: @user3324467 Glad we got it straightened out.

Comment: If the `StartDate` column is a `char` data type, without the OP specifying what exact format it is in how do you know it is natively sortable without converting to `date` in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: @ErikE, you are correct.  I dont.  As I say in my edit, his cast is correct.  His real issue however was just understanding `DESC` vs `ASC`